# using subquery instead of the tablename

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

```
Table Meta:
-------------------------------------
type                  tab_name
new                   tab_news
sports                tab_sps

Table tab_news
------
id

Table tab_sps
-------------------
id
xx
```

Now I want to use

```
SELECT id 
  FROM (SELECT tab_name 
          FROM Meta 
         WHERE type = 'news');
```

But it does not work, any ideas?

Comment: @OMG Ponies - The OP wants to get all of the data from the tab_news table.  Instead, the OP is getting the single record from the Meta table.

Comment: Hi I update the post, "BiggsTRC" is right,I want get the records of the tab_news table. And the error is "ora error:09004,invalid identifier "id");

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Yes, if you wanted to do it at design time. However, the OP wants to look up data from different tables based upon a value in a table.  For example, the next time we run the query, it might say to go to the tab_sps table instead.  The OP wants the query to change at runtime based upon information in the database.

Comment: Does oracle support dynamic sql?

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Yes, Oracle supports dynamic SQL.  See my answer for details.

Comment: So this setup is so that you can change the actual table name for 'news' type?  Why is this abstraction needed?  Why not just query the NEWS table?  Unless this is homework, try to keep things simple.  Also, Oracle will happily store metadata for you about the NEWS table or any other object you create ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL does not support a variable/etc for the table name -- the only means of supporting what you ask is by using dynamic SQL:

```
FOR i IN (SELECT tab_name
            FROM META m
           WHERE m.type = ?) LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM '|| i.tab_name ||'';
END LOOP;
```

Comment: The ORA-00904 error is because you can't reference columns that don't exist in the table or derived table/inline view.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax structure you are trying to use doesn't do what you want.
What appears in the FROM clause is a data set. This might be a table or a view. In your case the data set is a subset of "Meta"; specifically the column "tab_name" for rows with the type of "news".

```
SELECT id 
  FROM (SELECT tab_name 
          FROM Meta 
         WHERE type = 'news');
```

SQL is basically set oriented. You seem to want the "tab_name" to return a 'pointer' or a reference to a data set. That suggests a more object oriented approach. Rather than a table_name, the select from Meta would return instances of an object and the wrapper would use a method on that object to extract the details. That would be more of

```
SELECT tab_name.getId()
FROM Meta
Where type = 'news';
```

But I'd need a more 'business terms' description of the problem before trying to guess what the object structures might look like.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe what you are trying to achieve is possible.  If you are working with a programming language with this data, you could return the sub-query value first and then build a new SQL statement for the query you want.  However, building a dynamic query inside SQL like this does not appear to be possible.

I think you need to take a step back and look at your database logic.  There has to be a different way of doing this.  For example, since each table had to have the same layout, maybe you could do a union all and then filter the data to only what you really want.  You could do that at runtime with a sub-query.  The process would have a significant overhead if it scaled to much, but it might solve your root issue.  Basically, rethink your design.  There is a way to accomplish your end goal but it isn't down this path.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this before and this is the approach I ended up using. SQL returns an object rather than a plain text string, which the table name only accepts plain text I believe

Answer (score -1):

Try aliasing the subquery.

```
select * from  (select tab_name from Meta where type='news') as my_sub_query;
```

Comment: That wouldn't give the desired results.  It would still list just the one record from the Meta table instead of the table that the OP wanted.