# SELECT the FROM table with a sub select and modify the resulting table name

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have the follwing given **two** tables which can not be changed.

**1: DataTypes**

```
+----------------------+-----------------------+
| datatypename(String) | datatypetable(String) |
+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

*Example data:*

```
+-----------+------------+
| CycleTime |  datalong  |
+-----------+------------+
| InjTime1  | datadouble |
+-----------+------------+
```

**2: datalong_1 (data model does not matter here)**

I want to make a query now that reads the datatypetable attribute from the datatypes table, adds the `String` "`_1`" to it and selects all content from it.

I imagined it, from a programmatic perspective, to look something similar to this statement which obviously doesn't work yet:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT datatypetable FROM datatypes WHERE datatypename = 'CycleTime') + '_1'
```

How can I make this happen in SQL using HSQLDB?

Thanks to Leonidas199x I know now how to get in the `'_1'` in but how do I tell the `FROM` statement that the subselect is not a new table I want to read from but instead the name of an existing table I want to read from.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT RTRIM(datatypetable)+'_1' FROM datatypes WHERE datatypename = 'CycleTime')
```

According to this question which is identical to mine this is not possible:

[using subquery instead of the tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931549/using-subquery-instead-of-the-tablename)

:(

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and the expected output based on your sample data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also: the string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`  not `+` - HSQLDB allows for the non-standard `+` but it's better to stick with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain your data model in a little more detail? I am not sure I understand exactly what it is you are looking to do. 
If you are wanting to add _1 to the 'datatypename', you can use:

```
SELECT datatypename+'_1' 
FROM   datatypes
```

Comment: Basically there is one table that holds the information of which table-Prefix stores a specific datatype (Thats table Nr1). Then there are possible hundreds of tables that start with the prefix and end with "_" and the identifier, so "_1". I have given one example of such a table called "datalong_1". In total there exist 4 total prefix, one for each datatype (long, int, double, String). Now If I want to know which table stores the information for CycleTime for the Identifier 1 I have to extract the prefix from the datatypetable and add to it the suffix "_1"