# Changing tablename using dynamic sql instead of subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been stuck on this error for few hours.

I have parameterized this select query

```
--Original query
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM table1;
```

to this which erroring out ORA-00904: "A"."col1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

```
--Parameterized query
SELECT DISTINCT A.col1 as col1  FROM (SELECT cont_code FROM dt5_campaign_code 
                                    where code_id = &test_cont_id) A;
```

Nested query outputs

```
SELECT cont_code FROM dt5_campaign_code 
                                    where code_id = &test_cont_id;
```

[image]

Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931549/using-subquery-instead-of-the-tablename). Please help in translating this for my query.

Comment: The identifier used by the nested query is CONT_CODE. If you want the identifier CONT_CODE to become COL1, then you will need to alias that column in the nested query. **SELECT cont_code AS col1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A.col1 as col1
FROM   (
  SELECT cont_code
  FROM   dt5_campaign_code 
  where  code_id = &test_cont_id
) A;
```

The sub-query `A` does not contain a `col1` column.

You either want to use `cont_code` in the outer query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A.cont_code as col1
FROM   (
  SELECT cont_code
  FROM   dt5_campaign_code 
  where  code_id = &test_cont_id
) A;
```

or, alias `cont_code` to `col1` in the inner query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A.col1 as col1
FROM   (
  SELECT cont_code AS col1
  FROM   dt5_campaign_code 
  where  code_id = &test_cont_id
) A;
```

or, get rid of the sub-query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT cont_code as col1
FROM   dt5_campaign_code 
WHERE  code_id = &test_cont_id;
```

---

As a dynamic statement:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(30);
  v_cur        SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_str        VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT cont_code
  INTO   v_table_name
  FROM   dt5_campaign_code
  WHERE  code_id = 1; --&test_cont_id;

  OPEN v_cur FOR 'SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM ' || v_table_name;
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur INTO v_str;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_str);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE V_cur;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wpkPSGMN)

Comment: cont_code should output a table name. Both tables don't have any common columns. I just created a lookup table(dt5_campaign_code) to get the value from a cell i.e. used by outer select query.

Comment: Nested query should o/p a table name which is used by outer select.

Comment: @yashagarwal Your question does not make that clear and, in that case, you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Can you please help in some way. I'm not familiar with dynamic sql

Comment: Found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931549/using-subquery-instead-of-the-tablename . How can I this for my solution

Comment: I have edited the post. Please give it a try now

Comment: One last question if I put the dynamic solution like this in between SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( DECLARE........END)); . Will this run?

Comment: @yashagarwal No, it will not as you cannot merge SQL and PL/SQL statements like that. (But you can try that yourself and see that it fails.)

Comment: You are right. Since i'm helpless rn can you update your above solution which solves this SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( DECLARE........END));. I believe it will be a simple change for you and I will also start reading up more on dynamic sql

Comment: @yashagarwal This is significantly outside the scope of the original question. If you have a new question then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Okay I'll put it up in a couple of hours